# Rails, Passing a variable from the controller to the App Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

**In my controller:**

```
  def gettingstarted
    @title = "Getting Started"
        respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => true, :showLeftNav => false }
    end
  end
```

In my default application layout file **Layouts/application.html.erb**:

```
<% showLeftNav = true if local_assigns[:showLeftNav].nil? %>
<body style="<% if showLeftNav == false %>background:none !important;<% end %>">
```

Am I passing showLeftNav incorrectly from the controller to the layout?

Comment: Are you receiving any bugs? FYI this should, I think, be written as `<%- showLeftNav = true if local_assigns[:showLeftNav].nil? %>` with the `-` at the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not define this as an instance variable like the `@title`? That way you could just for the presence of it in the view and also default its value.

Answer (score 0):

local_assigns will be used in the templates (ActionView) to pass local variables to sub templates or a partial. For passing values from controller to view we will be using instance variables. [This page](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionView/Base) has an example showing how to pass local variables to sub templates and [this](http://www.pointstorm.com/~gavin/partials-doc/classes/ActionView/Partials.html#M000003) shows some Public Instance methods where local variables can be passed.